# How to add and remove class by click different buttons in angular?

Tags: angularjs

here in ng-class i use class1, on click of that the color is change to red, if i click on close button the class should be removed. i added the class but i dont know how to remove by close button. someone help me in it.

**html**

```
        <div class="name-awards"   ng-class="class1" ng-click="addAssociate('John M Kennady1 (111111)');associateInput = ''; ">
            <p class="name-awards-name">John M Kennady1</p>
            <p class="name-awards-id">(111111)</p>
        </div>        

         <div class="name-awards" ng-click="addAssociate('John M Kennady2 (222222)');associateInput = '';">
            <p class="name-awards-name">John M Kennad2y</p>
            <p class="name-awards-id">(123456)</p>

        </div>   
        <div class="addedAssociates">
            <div class="adass-close" ng-repeat="ass in addedAssociates">{{ass}}<button class="clsbtn" ng-click="remove($index)"></button></div>
        </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$scope.addAssociate = function(b){
if($scope.addedAssociates.indexOf(b) == -1){
$scope.addedAssociates.push(b);
 $scope.class1 = "red";
   }
}
$scope.remove = function (index) {
    $scope.addedAssociates.splice(index, 1);
    angular.element("[ng-class='class1']").removeClass("red")
 }
```

**CSS**

```
.red{color:red;}  .blue { color:blue;}
```

Comment: Did you try $scope.class1=null?

Comment: I agree, instead of trying to remove the class turn it to null.

Comment: i dint know about that null, can u give me small demo?? it will be very helpfull.

Comment: hey super i got it, but since i am using class it is affecting to all class where all i use. any solution for that??

Comment: Don't play with dom inside controller it is not good practice.

Comment: Agree with @squiroid , instead of playing with dom directly or setting class as null, I suggest using `a map of class names to boolean values. ` in ngClass.

Comment: hi here i want to apply that for more than one div, so by using same class if i do so the red color is applying for all the div, is there any thing like ng-id so that it will be unique so, if i click that text only that will change to red color?